# Lua library for recording sound

Tags: library, audio, audio-recording, lua

So I'm aiming to create a simple Lua program that takes input from the microphone and plays it back to the user (as a sort of mic test, fun project). Anyway, everything except the audio recording is done. Is there a library that will allow me to record audio from a user's microphone for however long a certain condition is true?